# Even after initialising, why am I getting this error?

Tags: swift

Why does this throw an error? I know I'm missing something trivial, but  it just keeps evading me:

```
var name = "John"

    var nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Coins: \(name)"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

The error shown is "Instance member 'name' cannot bemused on type ViewController"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `lazy` to be able to access `name`

```
lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vadian mentioned you need lazy, but why?

When you create variables and constants on class level they don't know of each other yet. It is in a very early initialising state. That's why you in some cases use `defer {}` to wait for everything to be initialised before calling the values.

`Lazy` works as a `defer {}` where the in your case variable with the `lazy` attribute wont be created until it's actually used. This means that the variable `name` will have had the time to be initialised.

Edit: Please mark @Vadiians answer as the correct one. This is just a deeper explanation.

Comment: in other cases we can say this, lazy can use after all variable and constants initialized completely in memory?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Yes, that is correct. And Lazy attributes wont be initialized in memory untill you actually decide to use it. for instance: Having a `UILabel` that is lazy but never added as a subview anywhere will never take any memory, while if it's not lazy it will still take up a memory slot even if it's not being used